# SQL Server pagination Query - Performance Consideration

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

Am working on SQL and am not so technical on the performance aspects. Am forming the Query dynamically using c# and with pagination purpose in my mind

every time on pagination click i fetch 10 records and my sample query like below

```
Select * 
from (Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TestId)[RowNumber],TestId...........) as paging  
Where RowNumber BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

where testId is the primary key.

Which works perfectly. i posted syntax as it is the confidential data. **It executes in say 6 secs**

if user clicks last page am forming the below query

```
Select * 
from (Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TestId)[RowNumber],TestId...........) as paging  
Where RowNumber BETWEEN 30000 AND 30010
```

**The above query takes 40 sec.**

What is the Core thing i am missing

Each time i get 10 records but a huge difference in time

Thanks

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996633/sql-retrieve-data-pagewise). It might help.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way around this problem, I'm afraid. With every method you have to somehow calculate the numbers for every row, and you either precalculate them in some temp table / indexed view, or let sql server do this on the fly (your current solution).

If you want to boost the performance of current query, add and index on TestId (even though it's already a PK) with included columns (you must include all columns that will be returned).

```
create index idxI__testid on <yourtable> (TestId) include (<column1>,<column2>)
```

But it only makes sense, if you want to return only a few of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

1) testid needs to be indexed. use INCLUDE (columns to return) when creating the index as suggested.

2) try to use select TOP. for example:

```sql
Select * from (Select TOP 20 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TestId)[RowNumber],TestId...........) 
as paging  
Where RowNumber BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```